# OAuth2 not working on Google Apps account with custom domain

Tags: mailcore2

I implemented OAuth support for Gmail and it's working great but if I login using a Google apps account (custom domain) I run into some issues. For example providerForEmail: doesn't work. Is there a workaround for this? I can set my hostname and port manually when creating a session but I pass MCOMailProvider around several methods in my app and I would need to change a lot of code plus the data model to store hostname/port separately.

Comment: Please take a look at it: https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/236

Comment: So I should modify MCOMailProvider?

Comment: It would probably require some refactoring in your code.

Comment: Ok, I thought that might be the case. If I modified MCOMailProvider to support OAuth2 logins would you be interested in a pull request or is that something you don't want/need to support?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what was required. Got it working via MXRecords - thanks for your help and the great library. Do you want to add an answer to the question so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect the email provider when the domain doesn't make it obvious, you need to do a DNS MX request. The result MX hostname can then be passed to `-[MCOMailProvidersManager providerForMX:]`.

The following issue on github documents how to perform a MX request:
https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/182